# How to reverse engineer WannaCry?

Tags: malware, ransomware, reverse-engineering, wannacry

I was reading [an article](http://thehackernews.com/2017/05/wannacry-lazarus-north-korea.html) today about a Google researcher linking the WannaCry malware to the earlier malware Cantopee.

I had two primary questions based on the contents of the article.

1. What do the numbers/addresses represent in this image?

   [image: Screenshot of tweet.]
2. Can someone explain to me what is going on here? Which tools are they using, and how would I do this myself?

   [image: Screenshot of programms displaying assembly code.]

Comment: The first screenshot looks very badly, I suggest to remove it from the question to get a better start on the site.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out [reverseengineering.SE](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/) for all your RE questions.

The name of the tool being used is [Hiew](http://www.hiew.ru/).

From [WannaCry — Links to Lazarus Group](https://blog.comae.io/wannacry-links-to-lazarus-group-dcea72c99d2d):

[image: software crypto hashes]

Some code in WannaCry (`9c7c7149387a1c79679a87dd1ba755bc`) beginning at address `0x402560` is the same as some code in Contopee (`ac21c8ad899727137c4b94458d7aa8d8`) beginning at address `0x10004ba0`. Same story for the next pair of addresses. In essence, both pieces of software share code.

This is what is depicted in picture 2 in the question, it is just a little hard to see. A bigger picture can be found in Dan Goodin's article [Virulent WCry ransomware worm may have North Korea’s fingerprints on it](https://arstechnica.com/security/2017/05/virulent-wcry-ransomware-worm-may-have-north-koreas-fingerprints-on-it/) (click to enlarge):

[image: Arstechnica Hiew disassembly]